# Why does .equals returns false while comapring identical strings?

Tags: java, string, compare, equals

im trying to compare a String, which is a part of read file(the file: 
Example of read file

```
1.Dog
2.Cat
3.Bird
```

4), to a given input by a user, using .equals.
It always returns false, even when i copypaste the printed String.

The code:

```
File TF = new File("Textfile.txt");Scanner read = new Scanner(TF);
String text="";
 while(read.hasNextLine()) {
        text = text.concat(read.nextLine()+"\n");
    }
    int x;
    int y;
    char a;
    char b;
    Random dice = new Random();
    x=dice.nextInt(3)+1;
    y=x+1;
    a=(char)(x+48);
    b=(char)(y+48);
    int first = text.indexOf(a);
    int second = text.indexOf(b);
    String some=text.substring(first,second);
    Scanner write = new Scanner(System.in);
    String writein=write.nextLine();
    System.out.println(writein.equals(some))
```

Comment: Print the two string that you are trying to compare and check

Comment: Print "some" and "writein" with S.O.P and see for yourself why ;)

Comment: @RR_IL i did that and, they are the same.

Comment: Note there is a flaw in your logic. When `a='3'` and `b='4'` then `text.indexOf(b) = -1`.

Comment: what if u do .contains?

Comment: Thanks for input guys, problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

`text.substring(first,second)` returns a string which contains a trailing line break, e.g. "1.Dog\n", while the string entered will not. To fix it, you could trim the line read from the file:

```
String some=text.substring(first,second).trim();
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable `some` ends with `\n` (or possibly `\r\n` on Windows). `writein` on the other has no trailing newline. When comparing strings, every character has to be equal (which is not the case).

You have multiple possible solutions to solve your problem. One of which is to call `stripTrailing()` on your string (Java >= 11).

```
System.out.println(writein.equals(some.stripTrailing()))
```

Or you could manually reduce the length of the string

```
String some=text.substring(first, second - 1);
```